Problem with Django and Python (the current path api/ did not match of these)
I am trying to set up a school journal based on Django and Python, but I can't do it because of a 404 page with a problem in the title.then Python part is backend and Node + Yarn + HTML is the consumer (client) part.
my views.py
from itertools import chain

from rest_framework import viewsets, mixins
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

from core.models import (
    StudyYear,
    Subject,
    Mark,
    StudentClass,
    Student,
    School,
)
from journal import serializers


class BaseJournalAttrViewSet(viewsets.GenericViewSet,
                             mixins.ListModelMixin,
                             mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,):
    """Base viewset for journal attributes"""
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)


class StudyYearViewSet(BaseJournalAttrViewSet):
    """Manage study year in the database"""
    queryset = StudyYear.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.StudyYearSerializer


class SubjectViewSet(BaseJournalAttrViewSet):
    """Manage subjects in the database"""
    queryset = Subject.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.SubjectSerializer


class MarkViewSet(BaseJournalAttrViewSet,
                  mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                  mixins.UpdateModelMixin):
    """Manage marks in the database"""
    queryset = Mark.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.MarkSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Retrieve all marks by student and subject"""
        queryset = self.queryset
        student = self.request.query_params.get('student')
        subject = self.request.query_params.get('subject')
        if student:
            queryset = queryset.filter(student__id=student)
        if subject:
            queryset = queryset.filter(subject__id=subject)

        return queryset


class StudentClassViewSet(BaseJournalAttrViewSet):
    """Manage classes in the database"""
    queryset = StudentClass.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.StudentClassSerializer


class StudentViewSet(BaseJournalAttrViewSet):
    """Manage students in the database"""
    queryset = Student.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.StudentSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Retrieve students for authenticated user by class"""
        student_class = self.request.query_params.get('student_class', None)
        queryset = self.queryset
        if student_class:
            queryset = queryset.filter(student_class__name=student_class)

        return queryset


class JournalAPIView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """Combine data from other serializer to form journal"""
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = serializers.MarkSerializer
    queryset = Mark.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Retrieve journal data from multiple serializers"""
        student_class = self.request.query_params.get('student_class', None)
        subject = self.request.query_params.get('subject', None)

        students_queryset = Student.objects.filter(
            student_class__name=student_class)
        mark_querysets = []

        for student in students_queryset:
            mark_querysets.append(student.marks.filter(subject__name=subject))

        queryset = list(chain(*mark_querysets))

        return queryset


class SchoolViewSet(BaseJournalAttrViewSet):
    """Manage school in the database"""
    queryset = School.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.SchoolSerializer

urls.py
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from journal import views


router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('study_years', views.StudyYearViewSet, basename='studyyrs')
router.register('subjects', views.SubjectViewSet, basename='subj')
router.register('marks', views.MarkViewSet, basename='markpage')
router.register('student_classes', views.StudentClassViewSet, basename='studcl')
router.register('students', views.StudentViewSet, basename='studentsview')
router.register('journals', views.JournalAPIView, basename='journaling')
router.register('school', views.SchoolViewSet, basename='allschool')

app_name = 'journal'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]

Code link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D_gP1GpL8MOJhLwWuw7UgQ_-ATHgLk_q/view?usp=sharing
$ python3 manage.py runserver
(runs successfully)
and then
Not Found: /
[20/Aug/2024 11:00:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2771
Client part:
$ yarn start
(success)
(And a blank React page.)

Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Using the URLconf defined in app.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    admin/
    api/user/
    api/event/
    api/timetable/
    api/journal/

The empty path didn’t match any of these.



if you check your root urlpatterns in app/urls.py, you can see:
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/user/', include('user.urls')),
    path('api/event/', include('event.urls')),
    path('api/timetable/', include('timetable.urls')),
    path('api/journal/', include('journal.urls')),
]

It means: in urlpatterns you never register view for empty path ''.
I offer you to add in app/urls.py:
urlpatterns = [
    # your urls
]
urlpatterns += [
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url="https://djangoproject.com/"), name="to-django"),
]

Last route will catch empty path and send redirect to django web site.
More here:
about url dispatcher: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/http/urls/ , there you can see examples with empty url.
about redirect: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview

Did not work ugh...

@КириллКулик - can you provide the new error stack?

i check your codebase. and improve the answer.

I have checked your code and provided a solution in my answer.

In DRF documentation:
from rest_framework import routers

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'accounts', AccountViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls

As you can see, you should use router.urls instead of urlspatterns.
So here is the solution:
in journal app urls.py
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from journal import views


router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('study_years', views.StudyYearViewSet, basename='studyyrs')
router.register('subjects', views.SubjectViewSet, basename='subj')
router.register('marks', views.MarkViewSet, basename='markpage')
router.register('student_classes', views.StudentClassViewSet, basename='studcl')
router.register('students', views.StudentViewSet, basename='studentsview')
router.register('journals', views.JournalAPIView, basename='journaling')
router.register('school', views.SchoolViewSet, basename='allschool')

and then in your app/urls.py
from journal.urls import router as journal
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/user/', include('user.urls')),
    path('api/event/', include('event.urls')),
    path('api/timetable/', include('timetable.urls')),
    path('api/journal/', include('journal.urls')),
]


Didn't work, that's problematic

If you want something on "/" url, then you need to edit
path('', admin.site.urls),

but you need to put something in that home path.
But you said that you are working with node and etc. then i suggest to handle this on client side, not backend.
